# Powershell, CSV-import

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm not very experienced working with CSV files, and now I'm kinda stuck getting this small private project to work properly.

I've made a script that checks which user who is running  the script, then gets the department number the user belongs to, from AD. Then I want to test that department number against a CSV file to get the correct Department name.

The CSV file look like this:

```
111;DepartmentBlue
222;DepartmentRed
333;DepartmentGreen
```

How can I make my script check if the Departmentnumber I got from AD, exists in this CSV file in column 1, and then return the Department Name (column 2)?

This is what I got:

```
Function outputData {
$outputUser.Text = ((Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties SamAccountName).SamAccountName)
$outputDep.Text = ((Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties Department).Department)

$dep = $outputDep.Text
$source = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Script\departments.csv"
foreach($i in $source){
    if($dep -eq $i){
       #give me the department name
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your CSV needs a column header for each of those fields on the first line. Then you can reference them by `$i.column1header` and `$i.column2header`. Also, since you are using semi-colon delimiter, you need to add `-Delimiter ';'` to your `Import-Csv` command.

Comment: the way that `-eq` and `-match` work against a collection is odd ... but useful in this situation. [*grin*] if you do `$Collection -match $Var` you will get all the objects that match the test. so ... replace the `foreach` with `$Source -match $Dep` to get the department object you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your current code, you could try the following:

```
Function outputData {

$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties Department
$dep = $ADUser.Department
$username = $ADUser.SamAccountName # Doesn't seem to be needed
$source = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Script\departments.csv" -Delimiter ';'
foreach($i in $source){
    if($dep -eq $i.departmentNumber){
       $i.departmentName
    }
}

}

outputData
```

All of this assumes that the first line of your CSV file is `DepartmentNumber;DepartmentName`. Alternatively, you could leave the CSV file without the headers and add the `-Header` parameter to your `Import-Csv` command like so:

```
Function outputData {

$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties Department
$dep = $ADUser.Department
$source = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Script\departments.csv" -Delimiter ';' -Header "DepartmentNumber","DepartmentName"
foreach($i in $source){
    if($dep -eq $i.departmentNumber){
       $i.departmentName
    }
}

}

outputData
```

This is all assuming the `Department` attribute in AD contains the department number value with the goal being looking up that same number in the CSV file and returning the corresponding department name on the same line. None of this code is efficient the way it is. We can accomplish this with less looping.

An alternative without looping and using the `.where()` function is the following:

```
Function outputData {

$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties Department
$dep = $ADUser.Department
$source = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\Script\departments.csv" -Delimiter ';' -Header "DepartmentNumber","DepartmentName"
$source.where({$_.departmentnumber -eq $dep},'First').departmentname

}
outputData
```

Another alternative is to use a string to hash table conversion like so:

```
Function outputData {

$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $env:username -Properties Department
$dep = $ADUser.Department
$source = (gc c:\temp\test1\test2.csv -raw) -replace ';','=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
$source[$dep]
}
outputData
```

Comment: Thank you alot! This makes sense, and will surely get me on the way:)